# Action of quantum channel on the state $|\alpha_x\rangle \langle \alpha_y|$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, coherent-states

Suppose we have a coherent state with amplitude $\alpha_x$ and density matrix $\rho_x := |\alpha_x\rangle \langle \alpha_x |$. This state is sent through a quantum channel. We do not have a concrete map representing this channel, but we know that at the output of the channel, we obtain a displaced thermal state, centered at $\sqrt{\eta}\alpha_x$ with variance $\frac{1}{2}(1+\eta \xi)$, where $\eta$ and $\xi$ are given. A thermal state reads

$$\rho_{th} = \frac{1}{1+\bar{n}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\bar{n}}{1+\bar{n}} \right)^n |n\rangle\langle n|,$$ where $\bar{n} = \frac{1}{2}\eta \xi$.

So, at the output we hold

$$D(\sqrt{\eta}\alpha_x) \rho_{th}D^{\dagger}(\sqrt{\eta}\alpha_x) = \frac{1}{1+\bar{n}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\bar{n}}{1+\bar{n}} \right)^n D(\sqrt{\eta}\alpha_x) |n\rangle\langle n| D^{\dagger}(\sqrt{\eta}\alpha_x).$$

---

Now, we assume that we send the state $\rho_{xy} :=|\alpha_x\rangle \langle \alpha_y|$ through the same channel. Can we say anything about the output of this state?

As, $\rho_x \mapsto D(\sqrt{\eta}\alpha_x)\rho_{th}D^{\dagger}(\sqrt{\eta}\alpha_x)$ it is tempting to say $\rho_{x,y} \mapsto D(\sqrt{\eta}\alpha_x)\rho_{th}D^{\dagger}(\sqrt{\eta}\alpha_y)$, but this is wrong, because $|\alpha_x\rangle$ is not mapped to $D(\sqrt{\eta}\alpha_x) \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\bar{n}}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left( \frac{\bar{n}}{1+\bar{n}} \right)^{\frac{n}{2}} |n\rangle$ (as $\rho_{th}$ is not purified by $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left( \frac{\bar{n}}{1+\bar{n}} \right)^{\frac{n}{2}} |n\rangle $.)

Does anyone have an idea how to obtain the output state of this channel, if $\rho_{x,y}$ is the input?

Comment: @PeterShor Thank you for your reply! So, you mean that probably even my preliminary about how the channel acts on $|\alpha_x\rangle \langle \alpha_y|$ might be wrong?

Comment: Why don't you have a concrete map representing the channel? If it's the channel that damps a coherent state by $\sqrt{\eta}$ and then thermalizes it, I believe there's a unique channel that does that (assuming that the relationship between $\eta$ and $\xi$ make such a channel possible). Find its explicit representation, and then apply it to $|a_x\rangle\langle a_y|$.

Comment: @PeterShor Thank you four your reply! As I haven't much experience in finding explicit channel representations, I did some research and found https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.3234, page 20-22, where I have to deal with the C(Loss) - case. So, it seems like I have to calculate the mixture of my input state with a thermal state at a beamsplitter with transmittivity $\sqrt{\eta}$. So, the representation of the channel via a beam-splitter matrix seems to be simple, calcuating the output explicitly seems to be very tedious. Did you refer to an attempt like this one, or do you have any easier way in mind?

Comment: No, that's the right representation. I would have mentioned beam splitters, but unfortunately I didn't remember that was how it worked when I wrote my comment.

Comment: To second Peter Shor's comment, it is not even clear that there is a unique channel doing that job (though still, all those channels might act in the same way on $\rho_{xy}$).